# Grails form submit generating blank entry at "params"

Tags: grails

I have this form and when the user types something this is submitted as `finalAnswer`, as you can see below:

```
        <g:form controller="animais" params="['rootNode': rootNode, 'finalAnswer': finalAnswer]">   
            <h3>${curQuestion} </h3>            

            <g:if test="${finished}">           
                <g:actionSubmit class="btn btn-primary" action="backToStart" value="Voltar" />
            </g:if>         
            <g:if test="${!finished}">
                <g:if test="${!showDivTip}">            
                    <g:textField name="finalAnswer" value="${finalAnswer}"/>
                    <g:actionSubmit class="btn btn-primary" action="submitFinalAnswer" value="OK" />                    
                </g:if>                             
                <g:if test="${showDivTip}">         
                    <g:textField name="tipToFinalAnswer" value="${tipText}"/>                   
                    <g:actionSubmit class="btn btn-primary" action="submitTipForAnswer" value="Finalizar" />                        
                </g:if>
            </g:if>
        </g:form>
```

The problem is that `finalAnswer` come to `params` as a 2-sized array of strings, even if the content is a simple string.

When I printed `params`:

```
[finalAnswer:[, leao marinho], rootNode:2, _action_submitFinalAnswer:OK, action:index, format:null, controller:animais]
```

Value of `params.finalAnswer`: `[, leao marinho]`

ClassType of `params.finalAnswer`: `class [Ljava.lang.String;`

How can I retrieve `params.finalAnswer` as a simple string?

Comment: I believe it might have something to do with having an input with name finalAnswer and passing a param with the same name. Since you have finalAnswer twice, the parser might take it as an array. It might be a good excercise to remove finalAnswer from the params of the form. Otherwise I would neet to see a bit of your controller code.

Comment: Also, where does the data from the finalAnswer in the form params come from? It might not be receiving data form anywhere so that is the reason why the item in [0] of your "finalAnswer:[, leao marinho]" is blank.

Comment: @OmarYafer you were right. At the first time, "finalAnswer" was null and at the second time, it had value and was attached at "params" as array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    <g:form controller="animais" params="['rootNode': rootNode]">   
        <h3>${curQuestion} </h3>            

        <g:if test="${finished}">           
            <g:actionSubmit class="btn btn-primary" action="backToStart" value="Voltar" />
        </g:if>         
        <g:if test="${!finished}">
            <g:if test="${!showDivTip}">            
                <g:textField name="finalAnswer" value="${params.finalAnswer}"/>
                <g:actionSubmit class="btn btn-primary" action="submitFinalAnswer" value="OK" />                    
            </g:if>                             
            <g:if test="${showDivTip}">         
                <g:textField name="tipToFinalAnswer" value="${params.tipText}"/>                   
                <g:actionSubmit class="btn btn-primary" action="submitTipForAnswer" value="Finalizar" />                        
            </g:if>
        </g:if>
    </g:form>
```

Comment: In fact, it worked. But it's still strange. What would be the cause?

Comment: It's because two inputs were generated with same id, and when you have this situation, you receive an array into the action controller. With this code, you avoid it. If solved, please mark it.

Comment: As I said to @OmarYafer at the root question, the problem was at first time, when "finalAnswer" didn't receive any value. I've changed the code to quindimildev's solution and it worked

Comment: As I needed "finalAnswer" at another GSP, I've created another to the code if "showDivTip" clause

Answer (score 1):

Answer by @quindimildev not fully right. Better will be use hidden field:

```
 <g:form controller="animais">   
  <g:hiddenField name="rootNode" value="${rootNode}"/>
  <g:hiddenField name="finalAnswer" value="${finalAnswer}"/>
        <h3>${curQuestion} </h3>            

        <g:if test="${finished}">           
            <g:actionSubmit class="btn btn-primary" action="backToStart" value="Voltar" />
        </g:if>         
        <g:if test="${!finished}">
            <g:if test="${!showDivTip}">            
                <g:textField name="finalAnswer" value="${finalAnswer}"/>
                <g:actionSubmit class="btn btn-primary" action="submitFinalAnswer" value="OK" />                    
            </g:if>                             
            <g:if test="${showDivTip}">         
                <g:textField name="tipToFinalAnswer" value="${tipText}"/>                   
                <g:actionSubmit class="btn btn-primary" action="submitTipForAnswer" value="Finalizar" />                        
            </g:if>
        </g:if>
    </g:form>
```

So you can remove it from params. Really, it more clear.